# Which are the js files that are being run when I run "npm start"?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular, npm, npm-start

I am trying to pick up angularjs v2 using the official documentation provided.

I followed the instructions on this page.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html

After I run `npm start`, I see a webpage http://localhost:3000/ being launched automatically on my default browser.

I see several js files in the quickstart folder. Which are the js files that are being run and in what sequence? Is there a main file that tells npm which files to run for `npm start`? How does npm knows which files to run?

Comment: Show your `package.json` content

Comment: Get into package.json file. You will get to know which file will start at first. Then from that file you can find each and every link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your package.json file there will be a "script" named "start".  The one you are running from is found here:  https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/package.json

```
"start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
```

It is executing the command `tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server"`

For usage of the `tsc` and `concurrently` node packages check out npmjs.com:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

Answer (score 1):

you can make a alert("file name") on every file to see which one run first or console.log("file name ") ;

Answer (score 1):

From `npm help start`

> This runs an arbitrary command specified in the package's "start" property of its "scripts" object. If no "start" property is specified on the "scripts" object, it will run node server.js.

So open package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
```

Just add something to it.

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "start": "arbitrary command"
},
```